# Iterate through a list of pairs in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of pairs eg. [("Word",3),("Test",1)] that I want to loop through and extract the key and value to pass to another function I've defined.

So in this case test function has a list of pairs and it's calling another function with the key and value of a pair. Obviously this throws an errors as it's incorrect but I'm not sure how to go about this.

```
test :: String -> String
test str = [another (fst n) (snd n) | n <- list]
   where list = genPairList

another :: String -> Int -> String
another str n = str ++ (replicate n 'T')
```

Comment: your test function return type should be `[String]`

Comment: After another look I don't really see a problem. If you remove the typing of test, it seems to be working. The real type of test should be String -> [String].

Comment: and I think the `where`-clause should read `list = genPairList str`, could you include the error and the definition of `genPairList` and maybe include an example of how you want to use this `test` function - I'd be interested in what string your input should be, and how the output would look like.

Comment: Ah @karakfa that seemed to solve it, yeah that was typo on where-cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write

```
 test list = [another w n | (n,w) <- list]
```

but notice that the return type is `[String]`

```
> test $ zip [1..] ["a","b","c"]
["aT","bTT","cTTT"]`
```

Comment: Return type was indeed problem, but I like the solution you provided for key value pair in the list

Comment: Alternatively, `test = map (uncurry another) . genPairList`